# Reading text file into dataframe where some texts need to be headers and those below them need to be column values

Tags: r, text

I have a text file which is of the below format.

```
Main Node

Node1

Some ABCD 

Some XYZ 

Node2

Some VMLK
Some LPO

Node3

LMK

POL

TOL
```

This needs to be transformed into a dataframe such as shown below.

```
Main Node        Node1          Node2         Node3
                 Some ABCD      Some VMLK     LMK 
                 Some XYZ       Some LP       POL
                                              TOL
```

In this case Main Node, Node1, Node2,Node3 will be the headers and the text below them would be column values. Every line would be each row.

Is there any way to achieve this in R

Comment: Is there any fixed structure to the data ie specific patter in column names or pre-determined lines at which header information will occur? If not, it will be difficult achieve what you ask. I example you gave actual data?

Comment: @Vince - The column names(headers) will always be same. The column values will always occur below the column names, till the next column name does not occur.

Comment: I guessed as much.  My answer attempts a solution, albeit using `awk` to help with data munging.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do this in `R` entirely.

Using `awk` I would first prepare the data:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=","; print "Node","Value" } $0~/^Node/ { node=$0; next } { print node, $0 } input_data.txt > output_data.txt
```

This should transform the data into something like:

```
Node,Value
Node1,Some ABCD
Node1,Some XYZ
Node2,Some VMLK
Node2,Some VMLP
Node3,LMK
Node3,POL
Node3,TOL
```

Then read into `R`:

```
df <- read.csv("output_data.txt", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)

dcast(df, Value~Node)
```

Doesn't give you exactly what you want, but pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt in R, albeit not very concise:

```
df=read.table("yourpath",sep="\n")
df=as.character(df[,1]);
colnames=c("Main Node","Node1","Node2","Node3")
start=match(colnames,df);
end=c(match(colnames,df)[-1]-1,length(df))
len=end-start;
df2=data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=length(colnames),nrow=max(len)))
colnames(df2)=colnames
for(j in 1:length(start))
{
if(len[j]>0)
{df2[(1:len[j]),j]=df[(start[j]+1):end[j]]}
}
```

Here, missing values are expressed as `NA`.